# XSSF skips the empty cells while reading the row values from excel file in C#

Tags: c#, .net

> > I am reading excel file using XSSF. while reading excel sheet by row
> >     wise if the empty cell is present in the row it tends to skip that cell value and
> >     auto populate it with next column which gives me the wrong output. what need to be change in the program to read the row exactly what
> >     is there in the excel including blank cell values.Below is my sample code.

```
 XSSFWorkbook wb =  new XSSFWorkbook(file);;
    XSSFSheet ws =(XSSFSheet)wb.GetSheetAt(0);
    for (i = 1; i <= ws.LastRowNum; i++)
    {                  
        XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow)ws.GetRow(i);//the code where empty cells are skipping
    }
```